# Change Screen resoultion in Oracle Linux running on Windows Hyper V

Tags: hyper-v, oracle-linux

How can the screen resolution of, the Guest OS: Oracle-Linux 7, running on Hyper-V, be changed? The reason this is required is that, there are scroll bars on the side and bottom that need to be traversed to get to the end of the Guest screen and this can get tedious.

I've tried installing the "[Linux Integration Services Version 4.0 for Hyper-V](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46842)". This was done based on previous experience with VMware, VBox and Hyper-V that needed some sort of "Guest Additions" or "Integration Services" to be installed in the Guest OS for its screen resolution to be adjustable.

For the "[Linux Integration Services Version 4.0 for Hyper-V](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46842)" to be installed, the Kernel the Guest OS was running needed to be the "Redhat Kernel" and not the Oracle-Linux 7 default [UEK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/technologies/uek-overview-2043074.html). I followed [this](http://www.ehowstuff.com/switching-default-uek-kernel-to-redhat-kernel-on-oracle-linux-7/) to get change the Kernel.

```
# grub2-set-default 0
# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
# init 6
```

*init 6 : reboots the OS.

This did not work, for me.

Next I tried something similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384602/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution), which says the following(for Ubuntu):

> - the poster has added "video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080" to /boot/grub2/grub.cfg. When I went to repeat this I noted the message about not editing /boot/grub2/grub.cfg directly so I have added the line in /etc/default/grub instead.

Did not Help either.

One more thing to note: I am a complete beginner with this OS.

Comment: I would love to know why this was down voted though, this was an actual question I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I finally had to do to get this fixed(after a full day of searching).

`grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1024x768"`

The source for this is [here](http://www.netometer.com/blog/?p=1663) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/085bf570-84cb-41ed-a7ee-ad8168dfa5b7/hyperv-and-linux-change-resolution-in-centos?forum=winserverhyperv).

The "1024x768" part of the code can be changed as required.

I suspect that installing the "[Linux Integration Services Version 4.0 for Hyper-V](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/technologies/uek-overview-2043074.html)" helped as well; Since the "**hyperv_fb**" is being used in the code.

Next, I will need to find out as to how I can enable "sharing the clipboard" between the Host and Guest OSs

Comment: Update: Just running the Grubby command given here was enough, without the "Linux Integration Services" on a fresh installation of Linux that was booted with the Linux Kernel(Oracle Linux Server, with Linux 3.10.0-123.el7x86_64). This probably works even if the server was booted other Kernels, but that needs to be tested.